# Import file issue in angular 2

Tags: angular, angularjs-scope, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I made a simple program of **hello** text in **angular 2**.I am able to make that program but i have some problem in understanding?

Here is my code 
http://plnkr.co/edit/BPdzCZeXbyzQrgmLzO86?p=preview

- I know **import** is a keyword **es6**  But on which file it is defined .Browser only understand java script like **(documnet.getElementByID())** how browser understand the **import**.on which file import is defined?

  import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
- where is **'angular2/core'** file ? and same where is this file 
  **import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'**
- Browser know the javascript file .Now I am using **.ts** or typescript file .which file is used to transcomplie the **.ts** to **.js** file before loading the browser.

I am not sure but I think this code is doing something to convert the **.ts file to .js file**.I need to know which file this code is using to transcompile the .js file ?

```
 <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript', 
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

any update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Converting from TypeScript ( .ts ) to JavaScript ( .js ) can be done in two ways. First ( best | recommended ) is to do that locally with tsc, gulp, grunt... Trough this process you define options like target output ( ES5 ), module type ( system or commonjs )... Result of this transformation is generated .js files. Second way it to use transpiler ( with including it in your script tags ), and do that process on the fly. This is very convenient for demoing stuff ( in Plunker for example )
2. Import and Export keywords are from ( es6 ), and they are implemented in TypeScript as well. If you use Import and Export, you must use loader like SystemJS or Webpack ( or any other ) on client. Without loader, it is not possible.
3. import from "angular2/core" or "angular2/http" is known to editors trough d.ts files which stand for TypeScript definition files. This files represent interface ( exported methods, classes, variables... ) for specific js library. It helps your IDE to recognize stuff available from your scripts.

I hope this is helpful :)